# how in c check what exactly is under /dev/sda and what is under /dev/sdb when both are USB drives

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I have problem in my c program which is transferring/copying data to/from /dev/sda and /dev/sdb.(open, read, write) Both devices are USB pendrives and their Major number is 8.

The problem i have is that minor numbers change exactly like the sda sdb names så after reboot i often write/read from/to the wrong one as the /dev/name become assigned to other device.

To make it more complicated the both USB devices are both connected to same USB bus (Raspberry Pi has only one) and have same size. What is different is the manufacturer name.

How to check the difference in c?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you should investigate `udev` and `/sys/` and perhaps `/proc/mounts` and other files under `/proc/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

udev should be solving that for you by creating unique names under /dev/disk which you can use instead of /dev/sda and /dev/sdb. The links under /dev/disk/by-id also include manufacturer name.

Comment: I tried to use names from /dev/disk/by-id/ but there is very strange thing happening. I do som disk restoring with dd on the devices and later on i do mounting. The Problem i encounter is fact that after dd there are (i see it in other cosnole with watch ls /dev/disk/by-id/) devices/ partitions of the device but the system claims they aren't there and mount fails. What is even more strange is the fact that if i use names like /dev/sd* everything goes flawless.

Comment: I don't quite get your description of what is happening. In any case all that is under /dev/disk/by-id must be symbolic links and you can see to which device they are pointing. And if some name is pointing to /dev/sda then it makes no difference whether you use that name of /dev/sda.

Comment: Sorry. It was my fault. I could see the device on the list but the /dev/by-id was not ready (checked with stat) to write on it. Because i did this everything inside a program everything was going really quickly and most probably the link was not fully initialized. When i introduced stat command between everything works fine. Thanks